# WiX - Error Applying Transforms

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX project that currently creates an MSI in English, French, Spanish and German. More languages to be added later. All of these installers work properly when run under the OS location setting as any English location (English-US, English-UK, etc.). The minute I change the location setting in the OS to any other non-english location, all the MSI files fail to run and give the error as below:

"Error applying transforms. Verify that the specified transforms paths are valid."

What exactly does this error mean purely from the context of an MSI installer? I have seen installers created by Java and MS Office also give the same problem. Their solution was to run a patch that they created for their MSI.

I want to understand what this error means so I can tweak my wix configuration files accordingly. The WiX documentation suggests making some changes using the Windows SDK that will essentially make one MSI, that automatically determines which language the MSI should run in, based on the location settings on that OS. I don't want to do that and lose the flexibility of having the OS location set as spanish, but still be able run the msi in english. As per my understanding of WiX's documentation, I will need to change the OS location from Spanish to English if I want to run the MSI in english. Should I drop the idea of WiX altogether for creating a multilanguage MSI?

Your thoughts, opinions on what other installer tools I could use to do the following...

The things I want the installer to do

- Prompt user for language selection
- proceed with installation in selected language
- skip the license agreement window
- Prompt for feature list
- Prompt for folder to install into
- install application binaries in selected language
- While un-installing, the language should be the language it was
  installed in.

Thanks for your time.